# automatic reference conversation inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance

I try to understand inheritance up to the hilt in OOP. So, I've exercised some tries. But, two points I'm stuck that one of them is `object slicing`. The other one is calling order of destructors. Why is `Box {carton}` need for right copy ctor? If `Box {carton}` is added, how can be carton type converted to Box type(I absolutely don't understand it).

```
// right ctor
/*
Carton(const Carton& carton) : Box {carton}, material {carton.material}
{ std::cout << "Carton copy constructor" << std::endl; }
*/
```

Code:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Box
{
protected:
    double length;
    double width;
    double height;
public:
    // Constructors
    Box(double lv, double wv, double hv);

    Box(double side) : Box {side, side, side}
    { std::cout << "Box(double) called.\n"; }

    Box() { std::cout << "Box() called.\n"; }

    double volume() const
    { return length * width * height; }

    double getLength() const { return length; }
    double getWidth() const { return width; }
    double getHeight() const { return height; }
    ~Box()
    { cout << "box destructor" << endl; }

    void print();

    // copy ctor
    Box(const Box& box) : length{box.length}, width{box.width}, height{box.height}
    { std::cout << "Box copy constructor" << std::endl; }
};


class Carton : public Box
{
private:
    string material {"Cardboard"};
public:
    Carton(double lv, double wv, double hv, const string desc) : Box {lv, wv, hv}, material {desc}
    { std::cout << "Carton(double,double,double,string) called.\n";}

    Carton(const string desc) : material {desc}
    { std::cout << "Carton(string) called.\n";}

    Carton(double side, const string desc) : Box::Box(side),material {desc}
    { std::cout << "Carton(double,string) called.\n";}

    Carton() { std::cout << "Carton() called.\n";}

    ~Carton()
    { cout << "cartoon destructor" << endl; }

    void print();

    // right ctor
    /*
    Carton(const Carton& carton) : Box {carton}, material {carton.material}
    { std::cout << "Carton copy constructor" << std::endl; }
    */

    Carton(const Carton& carton) : material {carton.material}
    { std::cout << "Carton copy constructor" << std::endl; }

};

int main()
{
    // Declare and initialize a Carton object
    Carton carton(20.0, 30.0, 40.0, "Glassine board");
    Carton cartonCopy(carton);             // Use copy constructor
}

// Ctor
Box::Box(double lv, double wv, double hv) : length {lv}, width {wv}, height {hv}
{ std::cout << "Box(double, double, double) called.\n"; }

// Redefinitions
void Box::print()
{
    cout << "Box printttttt" << endl;
}
void Carton::print()
{
    cout << "Carton printttttt" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that inheritance is a "is a" relationship. A `Carton` *is a* `Box`, which is why you can use a `Carton` when a `Box` is expected.

However be careful of the [object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing) problem. If a function takes a `Box` argument by value, and you pass a `Carton` object, the function will get only the `Box` part.

---

Also, you have another problem, in that your `print` function is not `virtual`. That means even if you have a pointer or reference to `Box` and pass a `Carton` the `Carton::print` function will not be called.

Lets illustrate this with an example:

```
void foo(Box const& box)
{
    box.print();
}

int main()
{
    Carton carton(...);
    foo(carton);
}
```

The above sample code will not have any object-slicing problems because the `foo` function gets a *reference* to the base class. However, it will print

```
Box printttttt
```

If you make `Box::print` virtual

```
virtual void print();
```

Then the above code will print

```
Carton printttttt
```

Comment: thanks for your help. But, how can the compiler pass `carton` as type `Box&` ? I don't understand that point.

Comment: @askque Read the first section of my answer again.

Comment: okey but why not by value (Box) instead of by reference (Box&) ?

Comment: @askque Because then you have slicing.